# Office 365 Video Portal Upload Errors

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, video, office-365-video-portal

I wonder if anyone has come across any errors regarding uploading of videos to the Office 365 Video Hub? I have attempted various sizes and all however the video fails to upload after 8mb. Video formatting is correct (attempted 4 various sizes and formats)

The page keeps asking me to leave and be redirected which then directs me to the following URL which then also shows a internal 500 error:

```
https://TENANT.sharepoint.com/portals/hub/_api/SP.RemoteWeb(@a1)/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(@a2)/CancelUpload(uploadId=@a3)?@a1='https%3A%2F%TENANT%2Esharepoint%2Ecom%2Fportals%2FTENANT%2FpVid'&@a2='%2Fportals%2FTENANT%2FpVid%2FVisitors%20Induction%20AFR%2Emov'&@a3=guid'02660eab-4e35-4ea5-9401-5367a71e9b1f'
```

If I stay on the page and not accept the redirect message I eventually get a upload error with a {Object Object] error as the description and access denied  message in the browsers console:

```
https://TENANT.sharepoint.com/undefined/_layouts/15/AccessDenied.aspx?Source=https%3A%2F%2FTENANT.sharepoint.com%2Fportals%2Fhub%2F_layouts%2F15%2FPointPublishing.aspx%3Fapp%3Dvideo%26p%3Du&Type=list&correlation=7994d49d-90cf-3000-a076-c3754e7fec09
```

When i inspect the console during the upload before the page redirect request the following forbidden errors show (I am site collection administrator for the site and the entire SharePoint Online instance). I have also granted myself direct permissions to the site collection from the admin centre for the site and the specific channel Im uploading to:

```
POST https://TENANT.sharepoint.com/portals/hub/_api/SP.RemoteWeb(@a1)/web/GetFold…2DChemicals%2FpVid%27&@a3=%27Visitors%20Induction%20AFR%2Emp4%27&@a4=false 403 (Forbidden)
```

This then resolves to the following error if I follow the URL:

```
<m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
<m:code>
-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientServiceException
</m:code>
<m:message xml:lang="en-US">
The HTTP method 'GET' cannot be used to access the resource 'GetByUrlOrAddStub'. The operation type of the resource is specified as 'Default'. Please use correct HTTP method to invoke the resource.
</m:message>
</m:error>
```

I am beyond stuck on this and cannot find a single solution, I have attempted this in multiple browsers.

Answer (score 0):

After some back and forth it seems it was locked down on a global administrator level. We uploaded using a global admin account and it worked 100%. There is no way to see this setting as a SharePoint Admin to see if it has been enabled or not it was  pure trial and error.